# Change Google Watermark GoogleMaps SDK

Tags: android, google-maps, maps

Is there any way to change the "***Google***" watermark Style in the bottom left corner of the Map in the **GoogleMaps SDK**? I have seen some Apps that change this logo to be white whitout black borders and I cant find any information about how to achieve this. I have only find a page to set the style of the map but not the logo.

Comment: I don't think its customizable ... You can not change/hide it .. It can be theme dependent but i am not sure ...

Answer (score 2):

You can not directly change color of logo. Hiding/overlapping logo is legally not allowed.

But you can change style of a map layout. see https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/

Download your json file for selected theme, put that in raw folder in res and write following code.

```
mMap = googleMap;
MapStyleOptions mapStyle = MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(this, 
R.raw.map_style_json);
mMap.setMapStyle(mapStyle);
```

--

According to your style color combinations, logo will be colored automatically.(e.g Dark theme -> light logo and vice a versa)